# Does Stack Overflow have a Windows Phone app?

Tags: support

I would like to have an app for my Windows Phone. If there is an app, can you provide a link to it?

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone

Comment: Did this really deserve a down-vote? It's a perfectly legitimate question evidenced by the fact that we currently _do not_ have one, which might lead someone to wonder if they missed it.

Comment: It deserves the down vote because a quick search on the app store would of given a pretty decent answer.

Comment: If there's no WP app, then why does the website ask me if I want to open it on the app when I visit it on my phone (taking up valuable screen space to do so)? Is it too stupid to realize I'm coming from my Lumia?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently there is no official Windows Phone app. [9 months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215992/stack-exchange-android-app-in-beta#comment699299_215992) there were no plans to make one, and as far as I know the situation hasn't changed.

You can vote on [Official Stack Exchange application for Windows Phone OS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225624/stack-exchange-application-for-windows-phone-os) if you would like Stack Exchange to make one.

Comment: Like I commented in the 'vote-question' you mentioned: `Regardless of the smaller audience, you're willingly ignoring a request from your users and that's a pity. Certainly since the request was propesed quite some time ago. I don't intend any criticism against you hard working people (no sarcasm) but I'd like to see a StackExchange app for Windows Phone since I really liked the Android version. :)`

Comment: @Abbas, given that there is a finite amount of development capacity, some requests from some users are going to have to be ignored.  There has to be prioritization of what development is most beneficial, and I see no reason to question the prioritization chosen.

Answer (score 15):

There is [Stack Mate](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/stack-mate/bab7c62e-859e-4566-a67d-3b0e00a120ac) which I find very good.

It allows you to read inbox, notifications and see statistics of your profile. You can place live tiles on the start screen which will notify you about new inbox messages and reputation changes.